# Exclude OPTIONS in external auth kubernetes ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have configured an external authentication in k8s by this annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "auth end point"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-method: GET
```

The external authenticator works with GET method.

The problem is with preflight requests (OPTIONS method). NGINX converts it in GET request and the authenticator return a 401 error (Authorization Required). Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @frederico, did you find a solution to this? I'm hitting the same issue that ingress is trying to authenticate OPTIONS which doesn't include the Authentication request header so it fails. I can't see anything in the documentation to get around this

Comment: No, I did not find a solution in the k8s ingress config. I had programmed my own auth system and I fixed this issue in this auth service. The request have the information of the original method in the header. Then I could filter this preflight request in the auth service and approve it.

Comment: Thanks. We did the same. We already had an external auth system and after looking at the code for the ingress controller we saw it was forwarding the `X-Original-Method` header.